# Launch navigator does not open google maps in ionic 4

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I am having trouble working with the launch navigator on my project developed on ionic 4.

I entered the necessary commands:

*ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator*

*npm install @ ionic-native / launch-navigator*

After that, I imported them into app.module as it is said.

With that, I implemented the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator/ngx';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teste-gps',
  templateUrl: './teste-gps.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teste-gps.page.scss'],
})
export class TesteGpsPage implements OnInit {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation, private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator) {
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }).catch(erro => {
      console.log(erro);
    })
  }


  navigateLocation() {
    let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
      start: [this.latitude, this.longitude],
      app: this.launchNavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS
    };

    this.launchNavigator.navigate('Laguna, SC', options)
      .then(success => {
        console.log(success);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

After that, I perform the command (ionic cordova run android) and the app opens on my phone, but when when the button that fires the navigateLocation method, there is no action, google maps does not open.

Does anyone know what can it be? If it is version issue or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it could be an issue with your API permissions. Try the following:

1. Visit [Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard). Select your Project.
2. Then click on the **Credentials** section in the left hand menu.
3. When the page loads, under the API Keys section, click on the relevant API key.
4. Check the **"Application restrictions"** section and make sure that the option that is selected, satisfies your purpose.
5. For testing purposes, under the **"API restrictions"** select the **"Don't restrict key"** option and Save. Then check after 10 minutes to see if it works.